# What does it mean to say 'to by' and 'up at'?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

[image]

I understand 'dictated by' but what does it mean by 'dictated to by'?Secondly,'lot at the mansion' is understood but 'up at the mansion' again confuses me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Can you please provide the text containing this quote? You have provided an image, but many people cannot use imgur.com.

Comment: I think the **to** belongs to the verb **dictate to**

Comment: Source : https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=pbJvV5bYOIvC8geI_7bYCA#q=lot+meaning , edited, hope it is clear now.

Comment: We live in a society that is dictated to by rules.

Comment: What is difference between 'dictated to by rules' and 'dictated by rules'?

Comment: If you ask me, I am not the right person, but I can guess that the phrasal verb version is more direct and focused than the other. I mean it does not have other usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I will not be dictated to by that lot up by the mansion.

*Dictate to* is a phrasal verb. See [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dictate-to-sb) and [The Free Doctionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dictate+to).

*by that lot* is a prepositional phrase. It gives you the agent of *will not be dictated to*, which is a passive construction.

*at the mansion* is is a prepositional phrase showing **where** *that lot* is located.

*up* means "in a high position." ([Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/up)). You can take it out of the sentence and the sentence would still be grammatical. Or the sentence could have a different 'directional' word such as *over* or *down*.

*Up* means that the *lot at the mansion* are somehow *higher* than the speaker. A typical meaning would be that the mansion (the whole mansion) is at a higher altitude than where the speaker is, or where the speaker usually is. *Down at the mansion* would mean the opposite. See Definition 1b, and the example sentences of 1b, in the [Merriam Webster Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/up).

Comment: The 'up' is still unclear, 'up at' means people on the upper floor of the mansion?

Comment: It's common and mostly okay to combine *up/down* with other prepositions expressing location, it combines the meanings.  E.g. *I was down outside of the pool* means you were both down and outside of the pool.  You can throw an *and* in between to be more clear - *I was down and outside of the pool.*

Comment: @AnubhavSingh: No, "up at" has nothing whatever to do with the upper floor. It is logically no different from "at", but has a connotation of implying that people at the mansion _as a whole_ are "up" from here. This might be literal (the mansion is on top of a hill) or it might be metaphorical (the people at the mansion are upper class).